# Reference on boundary behavior of conformal maps

Tags: cv.complex-variables, conformal-maps

I am looking for some results on the boundary behavior of conformal maps between simply connected domains. In particular I am interested in conformal maps between $\mathbb{C}-\Delta$, where $\Delta$ is an interval (in general, $\mathbb{C}-\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a Jordan arc) onto the exterior of the unit disc.
It is well known that every conformal map from $\mathbb{C}-\Gamma$ onto the exterior of the unit disc can be extended continuously to the boundary (Carathéodory's theorem). In the book *Boundary Behavior of Conformal Maps*, by Christian Pommerenke I found the following theorem:

> **Theorem 2.6** Let $f$ map $\mathbb{D}$ conformally onto the inner domain of the Jordan curve $C$ of class $\mathcal{C}^{n,\alpha}$ where $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ and $0<\alpha<1$. Then $f^{(n)}$ has a continuous extension to $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and
>   $$|f^{(n)}(z_1)-f^{(n)}(z_2)|\leq M|z_2-z_2|^\alpha,\;\; z_1,z_2\in\overline{\mathbb{D}}$$

Is there any reference to an analogue theorem from $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\mathbb{C}-\Gamma$?

Answer (score 2):

1. You stated Caratheodory's theorem incorrectly. Conformal map of $C\backslash\Gamma$,
   where $\Gamma$ is a Jordan arc, onto the exterior of the unit disk NEVER extends to a continuous map between closures. It the INVERSE map that extends.
2. The more general statement of Caratheodory's theorem says that a conformal map
   of the unit disk onto a region $D$ extends to a continuous map of the closure of the disk to the closure of $D$
   if and only if the boundary of $D$ is locally connected. This contains the case you are asking about. The good reference for this more general theorem is
   J. Milnor, Dynamics in one complex variable: introductory lectures (available free on the Internet).
3. To prove smoothness, you "open" your arc. Let $a,b$ be endpoints.
   Suppose for simplicity that $a=-1$, $b=1$,
   which does not restrict generality. The composition $g(z)=J^{-1}(f(z))$,
   where
   $$J(z)=1/2(z+1/z)$$
   is the Joukowski function,
   is well defined and analytic in the unit disk for any fixed
   branch of the $J^{-1}$ by the Monodromy theorem. Then $g(z)$ maps the unit disk onto a Jordan region, and Pommerenke's statement applies to it.
   Then see what this implies for $f$ by differentiating the composite function. It implies the same except at
   the preimages of $a$ and $b$ on the unit circle. But the boundary of your
   region is not smooth at these points.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the mistake, but I understand the closure of $\mathbb{C}-\Gamma$ taking the limits in the upper and lower banks of the arc. I just search in Milnor's book but there is no the result I am looking for. I need a stronger result than Carathéodory's, because I am looking for smoothness on the boundary of the conformal map.

Comment: In this case, what is $f$?

Comment: $f$ is the function mapping the unit disk on $\overline{C}\backslash\Gamma$.